# How to write char and integer into binary files with specificed precison using python?

Tags: python, matlab, binary, unsigned-integer

My original idea is to write a python version of this MATLAB function [cmp2pal](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43114-cmap2pal-convert-matlab-colormap-to-binary-pal-format). I want to use python's colormap and transform it into pal files which can be used in origin and I don't want to open my matlab. The function's most important part is the following:

```matlab
    %% Open file
    fid=fopen(path,'w',mf);
    if(fid<0)
        throw(MException('cmap2pal:Open','Error opening file (%s) for writing',path));
    end

    %% Write RIFF signature
    fwrite(fid,'RIFF','uint8',0,mf);
    
    %% Write file length
    fwrite(fid,flen-8,'uint32',0,mf);                               % 8 byte header (RIFF header)
    
    %% Write PAL signature
    fwrite(fid,'PAL ','uint8',0,mf);
    
    %% Write data signature
    fwrite(fid,'data','uint8',0,mf);
    
    %% Write data block size
    fwrite(fid,flen-20,'uint32',0,mf);                              % 20 byte header (RIFF + Chunk)
    
    %% Write version number
    fwrite(fid,[0,3],'uint8',0,mf);                                 % Always 3
    
    %% Write palette length
    fwrite(fid,depth,'uint16',0,mf);
    
    %% Write palette data
    fwrite(fid,[cmap.*255,zeros(depth,1)]','uint8',0,mf);           % RGBA tuples
    
    %% Close file
    fclose(fid);
```

I searched for the solution but I still don't understand how the char or string can be saved as binary format (unsigned integer with precision). Can anyone give me the correct python version of this function? I used the struct module but there are errors:

```
# %%
import struct
newFileBytes = 'RIFF'
# make file
newFile = open("testpython.txt", "wb")
# write to file
# newFile.write(newFileBytes)


newFile.write(struct.pack('4B', *newFileBytes))
# %%
```

the error message

```py
----> 10 newFile.write(struct.pack('4B', *newFileBytes))

error: required argument is not an integer
```

Comment: what is in `newFileBytes` ? And why do you use `*` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have string

```
newFileBytes = 'RIFF'
```

but you need bytes

```
newFileBytes = b'RIFF'
```

And then it will work

```
struct.pack('4B', *newFileBytes)
```

But if you have bytes then you can write it directly to file

```
newFile.write(b'RIFF')
```

---

If you want to keep it as string then use `encode` to get `bytes`

```
newFileBytes = 'RIFF'.encode()

newFile.write( 'RIFF'.encode() )
```